# Способ скоростной проверки IP-адреса на уникальность

Tags: php

На сайте посещаемость 100.000+ в сутки. Нужно каждого посетителя проверить на уникальность (за сутки).
Решение было такое: складывается каждый айпишник в бинарном виде (4 байта) в файл. потом ищет в нем. Но это создает нагрузку на сервак. Нужно без баз данных, и без кук. Подскажите красивое решение.

Comment: Файл — тоже база данных, только примитивная и самодельная.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Проверить на уникальность - раз в сутки или за всё время? file_exists() может поможет?

Comment: За сутки. В 00:00 статистика обнуляется.

Comment: Что-нибудь наподобие этого не подойдёт?

    $filename = str_replace('.', '/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if ( !file_exists($filename) ) { создаём файл }
    else { посетитель есть }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два варианта:

1. memcached
2. модуль веб-сервера

Если только IPv4, 1 адрес = 4 байта. 200тыс = 800000 байт —  меньше 1Мб, можно держать в памяти.

**Memcached**
Поднять сервер memcached на минимальной памяти, держать ip в нём. Запросы будут весьма быстрыми: "есть ключ?". Сложный момент тут — обнуление. Можно поставить срок жизни ключа в сутки, но это не значит, что он сотрётся через 24 часа, просто попадёт в кандидаты на мусоросбор. А делать какой-то собственный механизм очистки кэша, хранить ещё и timestamp'ы каждому ip — какое-то усложнение, выходит.

**Модуль веб сервера**
Apache у вас, или nginx — оптимально будет уже в нём разбираться с уникальностью посетителя. Сервер первым узнаёт ip клиента, и может, "спросив" свою оперативку, где он держит этот 1Мб активных ip, или сторонний memcached, добавить к запросу заголовок, напр. "UniqueIP: true" или "false".
Более распостранённая похожая задача - ограничение соединений с одного ip в единицу времени, под неё точно есть готовые модули. Либо можете разработать собственный модуль к вашему веб серверу, который будет заниматься допиской заголовка и удержанием в оперативке кэша ip адресов.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще говоря, хорошо настроенная БД будет, наверное, самым грамотным подходом. Но раз нет, то нет.

Предположим, сайт работает только по IPv4 и IPv6 ему никак не светит — тогда можно завести файл с банальной битовой картой, 1 адрес = 1 бит, уложимся в 512 мегабайт. Читать его весь, разумеется, не нужно.

Минусы — это требует много памяти (на диске), плюсы — гарантированный доступ за O(1), быстрее некуда. Если бы не одно «но» в виде требования блокировок и неумения PHP в сисколл `fcntl`.

Смещение в файле определяем как:

```
$ip_long = ip2long($ipv4);
$offset = intval(floor($ip_long / 8));
$bitmask = 1 << ($ip_long % 8);
```

Проверку производим как-то в духе:

```
$fh = fopen("visitors_ipv4.bin", "rb+");
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);                      // Да, это проблема. См. далее.
fseek($fh, $offset, SEEK_SET);
$octet = ord(fread($fh, 1));
$is_new_ipv4 = $octet & $bitmask === 0;
if ($is_new_ipv4) {
    fseek($fh, $offset, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite($fh, chr($octet | $bitmask), 1);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Обработку ошибок я тут, для простоты, не писал. Результат в `$is_new_ipv4`.

Перед этим нужно убедиться, что файл `visitors_ipv4.bin` существует и содержит (2^32)/8=536870912 нулевых байт (512 мегабайт). Раз в сутки, соответственно, файл надо обрабатывать и чистить (чтобы не тормозить дело — создаем новый `visitors_ipv4.bin.new`, переименовываем старый `.bin` в `.bin.old`, переименовываем `.bin.new` в `.bin`, спокойно обрабатываем).

Крупная проблема этого — сериализация запросов из-за `flock`, одновременно с файлом может работать только один поток.

Если PHP умеет [`fcntl`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.dio-fcntl.php) (который может  в правильные блокировки, с указанием блокируемой области), то обязательно стоит переписать этот код с его использованием (блокировать один октет по смещению `$offset`), если нет — извините, нужно другое решение.

Без блокировок будут случайные потери, какой-то IPv4-адрес будут дважды считать «новым», какие-то адреса будут пропадать из списка.

Comment: @drdaemon, 100000 запросов в сутки - это чуть больше 1 запроса в секунду. 

     Если PHP умеет fcntl   .... если нет — извините, нужно другое решение.

Не думаю, что стоит волноваться по поводу блокировок.

Comment: Ну, они, я так думаю, нерегулярны. В часы пик — десяток-другой запросов в секунду, в спокойные часы — полтора посетителя, и те — Googlebot с Yandexbot'ом.

Я подозреваю, что цифры онлайна между минимумом (раннее утро) и максимумом (поздний вечер) расходятся чуть ли не на порядок.

Comment: @drdaeman, мне самому стало интересно, какие цифры при какой нагрузке можно получить. Написал тест, который в течении 10 секунд из нескольких процессов постоянно вызывает (через system()) программу, делающую flock() на файл 512MByte и изменяющую один случайный байт в нем.

Результаты (в скобках изменений в сек. на один процесс):

    N proc  sec  total op/sec
    100     10   12778 1277  (12)
    30      10   12298 1229  (40)
    10      10   35180 3518  (358)
    2       10   15334 1534  (767)
    1       10    7492  749  (749)

Как видите суммарно (при высокой нагрузке) около 1000 в сек.

Comment: @avp: Бенчмарк интересный, но, как мне кажется, бесполезный. Разве что бенчмарк как показатель вероятного характера зависимости производительности от нагрузки.

Проблема в том, что что сервер будет занят явно не только подсчетом адресов. Плюс добавляем неизвестную эффективность кэша VFS (мало свободной памяти = резкое падение производительности), плюс работа шедулеров (что процессов, что I/O), плюс погода на Марсе… В общем, даже имея параметры железа и относительные цифры загрузки я бы не особо рискнул предсказывать сколько оно вытянет. Не знаю.

(BTW, как я понял, 100k уников, а не запросов)

Comment: Потестировал еще. Мне показалось, что первый результат был слишком хорош, что ли, для моего не самого быстрого диска. Я списал это на то, что делал файл в 500M truncate()-ом. 

Теперь сделал его честно, прописал байты в каждый  блок (4К), но результаты практически не изменились. Посмотрел зависимость от блокирования доступа к файлу. При малом количестве процессов ничего не меняется. При большом (десятки) блокирование замедляет раза в два.

Процессор данная задача практически не грузит (понятно, все время уходит на беготню по диску).

Вывод - сотни (ближе к 1000) операций в секунду.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю более красивое решение. Делаем 256 папок (на самом то деле их будет меньше, но зачем заморачиваться?). И в каждой папке делаем по 256 документов. Теперь имена папок - это первый октет, имена файлов - второй октет. В результате в каждом файле будет не более 64к строк. А если их время от времени сортировать и применять бинарный поиск, то и ещё быстрее. Конечно, можно сделать и двойное вложение папок и делить не обязательно по октетам, да и папки не объязательно сразу все создавать - это все детали.

Этот способ будет быстрым ещё тем, что если зашли два разных пользователя, то будут с большой вероятностью открыты два разных файла, не будет взаимных блокировок, что в результате приведет к некоторому ускорению.

Comment: @KoVadim, при таком подходе я бы строил иерархию с **последнего** октета. Это эффективно рассеит запросы по оглавлениям.

Хотя, как я заметил в комментарии к ответу @drdaemon, поток запросов так мал, что все эти ухищрения неактуальны.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал что-то типа сервера, который постоянно хранит в памяти список ip адресов и по умному сортирует для быстрого поиска. Типа тех же счетчиков, которые можно повесить на сайт.
А вообще тут три варианта:

Хранить в файле. 512 мегабайт и постоянное обращение к ним.

Хранить в БД. Индексы настроить и должно работать шустро. Нагрузка на диск возможно больше чем в первом случае.

Хранить в памяти. Никакой нагрузки на диск, но и задача сложнее.

Comment: По идее, у БД нагрузка на диск может быть и меньше, если памяти много, а сервер на хорошем ИБП и с хорошим контроллером. Кэш от 512-метрового файла, при хорошо разбросанных адресах, почти наверняка больше страниц в памяти займет. Наверное.

Comment: БД намного больше пишет и никакие кэши не помогут писать меньше 1 раза. И она должна сохранять данные сразу на случай внезапного падения системы или еще чего подобного.

Comment: Зависит от БД. Для таких данных обычно, если БД позволяет, требования к персистентности ослабляют. Скажем, до «если вдруг из-за аварии потеряем последние 15 минут, да и шут-то с ними.»

Comment: откуда взялся объём в пол-гига?!

Comment: 1 бит для каждого из 4миллипрдов адресов, получится 512Мб.